# Why would it be necessary to use (&*ptr) this format?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am reading sample code regarding to how to write destroy():

```
template<class T>
inline void destroy(T* pointer)
{
    pointer->~T();
}

template <class FowardIterator>
inline void 
_desstroy_aux(ForwardIterator first,ForwardIterator last,_false_type)
{
    for(;first<last;++first)
    destroy(&*first); 
}
```

I am not so sure about why using

```
&*first
```

I suppose the destroy algorithm is often used with the assumption that the iterators point to allocated memory. So why don't we use `destroy(first)` directly? Maybe because `first` could point to elements which are not individually allocated？

Comment: does the single-argument destroy take an iterator as an argument?

Comment: @user253751 Yes it does. Sorry I forgot to add the destroy function defination

Comment: So the answer is actually no, it doesn't - it takes a pointer

Comment: Well, `first` might not be a pointer, and `destroy` takes a pointer.

Comment: You don't nead define it it is already defined by standard: `void std::destroy_at(auto*);   void std::destroy(auto first, auto end);    void std::destroy_n(auto first, size_t N);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `&*ptr` in C++ is used to obtain a pointer to an element pointed to by an iterator. In the context of the provided code, `&*first` is being used within a function that is responsible for destroying objects (called `_destroy_aux`).

The main reason to use `&*ptr` in this case is to get a pointer to the object that the iterator points to first. This is necessary because the destroy function (or 'destory', depending on the possible typo in the code) may require a pointer to the object to be destroyed.

The `*` operator gets the object pointed to by the iterator first, and then the `&` operator gets the memory address of that object, thus providing a pointer to the object itself. This memory address is what may be needed to be passed as an argument to the destroy function to perform the destruction of the object pointed to by that iterator.

Comment: even more pedantically it should probably be std::addressof(*first). I bet the & is a bug in some weird cases.

Comment: @user253751 — overloaded `operator&`.